# shell bash - How to split a string acoring to a delimeter and echo each substring to a file

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

Hi I am trying to split a string  am getting from a file, using the delimiter "<" I then want to echo each string to a file. I am sort of there, but am not sure how to best split the string and then loop echo each substring (there may be up to 10 substrings) I am guessing I need to create an array to store these strings and then have a loop to echo each value?

Here is what I have so far:

```
while read line
do
   # ceck if the line begins with client_values=
   if[["$line" == *client_values=*]]
        CLIENT_VALUES = 'echo "${line}" | cut -d'=' -f 2'

        #Now need to split the  CLIENT_VALUES using "<" as a delimeter.
        # for each substring
            echo "Output" >> ${FILE}
            echo "Value $substring" >> ${FILE}
            echo "End" >> ${FILE}

    done < ${PROP_FILE}
```

Comment: Would help if you gave sample input and expected output here. The `awk` answer I gave should work, as should `Alfe's` though it's not clear what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^client_values=' < "${PROP_FILE}" | while IFS='=' read name value
  do
    IFS='<' read -ra parts <<< "$value"
    for part in "${parts[@]}"
    do
      echo "Output"
      echo "Value $part"
      echo "End"
    done >> "${FILE}"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

One line `awk` might be simpler here (and you get the added bonus of having the angry face regex separator `=<`)

```
$ awk -F "[=<]" '/^client_values/ { print "Output"; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "Value " $i; print "End"}'  input.txt >> output.txt
$ cat input.txt
client_values=firstvalue1<secondvalue2<thirdvalue3
some text
client_values=someothervalue1<someothervalue2
$ cat output.txt
Output
Value firstvalue1
Value secondvalue2
Value thirdvalue3
End
Output
Value someothervalue1
Value someothervalue2
End
```

Your answer could probably also work, I think with minimal modification, you would want something like

```
#!/bin/bash
PROP_FILE='input.txt'
FILE="output2.txt"
while read line
do
   # ceck if the line begins with client_values=
   if [[ "$line" == "client_values="* ]]
   then
        CLIENT_VALUES=`echo "${line}" | cut -d'=' -f 2`
        IFS='<' read -ra CLIENT_VALUES <<< "$CLIENT_VALUES"
        for substring in "${CLIENT_VALUES[@]}"; do
          echo "Output" >> "${FILE}"
          echo "Value $substring" >> "${FILE}"
          echo "End" >> "${FILE}"
        done
  fi

done < "${PROP_FILE}"
```

Which produces

```
$ cat output2.txt
Output
Value firstvalue1
End
Output
Value secondvalue2
End
Output
Value thirdvalue3
End
Output
Value someothervalue1
End
Output
Value someothervalue2
End
```

Though again, not sure if that's what you want or not.